# Existence of minimum

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis

I'm looking the proof to show that a set $S$ is open iff each point in $S$ is an interior point.

Def) A set is **open** if it does not contain any of its boundary points

Def) A point $z$ is said to be a **boundary point** of set $S$ if point $z$ is neither interior point nor exterior point

Def) A point $z$ is said to be an **exterior point** of a set $S$ when there exists a neighborhood of it containing no points of $S$

Def) A point $z$ is said to be an **interior point** of a set $S$ whenever there is some neighborhood of $z$ that contains only points of set $S$

The proof goes on like this.

'Let $G$ be an open region in $\mathbb C$ and $dG$ denote it's boundary. Let $a \in G$ be any point in $G$. Choose $\epsilon = \min\{|a-b|:b \in dG\} $ then region $|z-a|<\epsilon$ is contained in $G$. So $a$ is interior point of $G$ and as $a$ was chosen arbitrary, all points of $G$ must be interior point.'

But is the $\epsilon$ defined by using the min well-defined all the time? I think there might be some exceptional cases when $dG$ is infinite. So I feel a little doubtful on this proof. (I know the proof without using any 'min' but still want to figure out the validity of the above proof.)

Comment: What's your definition of an open set?

Comment: Is $C = \mathbb C$, the complex plane?

Comment: @Don Thousand Oh, I edit the definition of open and related topological concepts on my question.

Comment: @Arctic Char Yes C is the complex plane(sorry for my poor mathJax level...). I think there might be some problem if the region is related to the $\mathbb Q$ or something.

Comment: The boundary might be infinite. But it is a closed set (intersection of closure of $G$ and closure of its complement). Then take a closed disk having $a$ as center with radius large enough to have a non-empty intersection with the boundary. Then this intersection is closed and bounded, so is compact. That implies that a minimum  must exist.

Comment: @drhab So... if there is a case that closed disk having any $a$ in $G$ as center with radius large enough cannot make any non-empty intersection with the boundary, the boundary itself must be empty set?

Comment: Yes, if a set $S$ is non-empty then *always* you can find some $r>0$ with $B(a,r)\cap S\neq\varnothing$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let it be that $\partial G$ is infinite.

It is our aim to show that for fixed $a\in\mathbb C$ there exists some $b\in\partial G$ such that $|a-b|\leq|a-x|$ for every $x\in\partial G$.

First note that $\partial G$ as intersection of the closed sets $\mathsf{cl}(G)$ and $\mathsf{cl}(G^{\complement})$ is closed.

Now find positive $r$ such that $F:=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid|z-a|\leq r\}\cap\partial G\neq\varnothing$.

Then $F$ is bounded and closed, hence is compact.

On $F$ we have the continuous function prescribed by $z\mapsto|a-z|$ and a continuous function on a compact set takes a minimum on that set.

Now let $b\in F$ such that $|a-b|$ is that minimum.

Then $b$ has the property mentioned above.